# Lua with C++ performance issues/lag spikes

Tags: c++, lua

I'm developing a game where I use (SFML) C++ for the core and Lua for the actor scripts. However, I'm running into some performance issues and I'm not sure what could be wrong. I've created a test program that shows the issue I'm having.

Basically, sometimes when I call a Lua function from C++, it takes much longer to return than usual. I need my game to run at 60 fps, and it does most of the time, but occasionally one or more of the function calls will take much longer than usual.

My first thought was that it was the memory manager, but turning it off didn't seem to get rid of the spikes. I know that there are several games that use Lua, and I imagine this is not a problem for them.

People have suggested that using LuaJIT could fix the issue, so I downloaded and set up LuaJIT (with lua 5.1). I got significantly improved average times, but the spikes were just as prevalent as ever:

[image]

Gallery of 2 examples of the console results (in microseconds; for reference a frame at 60 fps is ~16700 I think):

gc off
[image: gc disabled]
gc on
[image: gc enabled]

C++ test program - http://pastebin.com/RhYnnLm3
Lua test script - http://pastebin.com/NBnAXcVD

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running on? My first guess would be the OS needs the CPU for some other purpose.

Comment: What hardware information do you need? My processor is Intel Core i7 3.2 GHz

Comment: Is it always the same function call that exhibits this behavior? If so, have you tried commenting out parts of the function to see if this stops?

Comment: It seems that the actual code in the call doesn't matter in terms of the spikes. I posted a test case which shows the problem happening on just a simple loop.

Comment: Have you tried not calling lua at all? Are you sure it is indeed inside lua? If indeed it is coming from just lua running at all, then the next step would be to run a profiler, because that seems like pretty strange behavior.

Comment: Could You be so kind and tell how to compile this beast? In Your case I'd try something more like [`Lua module approach`:](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModuleDefinition) script returns `Lua table` with some `local` defined `function` entries. Not sure but it **MIGHT** reduce Your function call delay, because accessing `local variables` is usually a bit faster.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is only in Lua. I've tried running Shiny profiler but I'm not too experienced with it and so far have been unable to find anything that would help me solve the problem. I will check out the module approach, but its the fact that the performance suddenly spikes which is the issue, not the speed overall, so I'm not sure if that would solve it.

You probably only need Lua to compile. I don't think the SFML has anything to do with it.

Comment: Do you observe the same spiking patterns with a different timer, such as `clock`?

Comment: Stuck with LuaBridge namespace error. Screw it.

Comment: You don't need the LuaBridge line either. That is a mistake, sorry. I left it in there on accident as I was narrowing down my test case.

Comment: If it's not GC a classic thing that could be happening is that you keep appending to a table.. whenever it doubles (or so) you get a reallocation hit.

Comment: It could be your binding layer creating temp objects. Step into the call directly in your debugger. You might find unexpected calls there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're experiencing LUAs garbage collector rolling in on some of your calls.  Typically in games you want to pay very close attention to how the GC operates, and how often it runs.  A simple solution may be to manually run the GC once per frame.  Some popular game engines I know of do that.  http://lua-users.org/wiki/GarbageCollectionTutorial

Comment: I have the line commented out on the pastebin, but I've tried it with the GC turned off (if my code is correct)

Answer (score 0):

The first suspect when having those spikes is the garbage collector.  The easiest "fix" to try first is not disabling it, but rather calling it at predictable times.

Try calling `collectgarbage()` or `collectgarbate('step')` once just at the end of your frame processing.